# Cómo hacer que dentro de una iteración, una función tome valores distintos

Tags: python, lista, random

Favor su ayuda para entender cómo al llamar a una función (en este caso llamada `juego_cartas`), hacer que esta me dé valores diferentes cada vez.
En un caso en particular me dio el mismo promedio para cada iteración.

```
for j in lista_prob_obj:       
    while contador_iteraciones<10:
    listado_prob.append(juego_cartas(j))
    contador_iteraciones=contador_iteraciones+1
    promedio=mean(listado_prob)
    lista_prom.append(int(promedio))
    print(promedio)
...
```

Cabe destacar que a la función `juego_cartas` (que hace un montón de cosas) le incluí la funcion `random.seed`. Pero como que al iterar se queda con el primer cálculo obtenido .

```
def juego_cartas(prob_obj):     
    #para hacer que el mazo sea aleatorio
    np.random.seed(1)
...
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Es que no puede ser de otra forma, por la ley de los grandes números la media de una distribución uniforme es el punto medio. Por eso siempre te da lo mismo. Si diera otra cosa es que aún llevas pocas repeticiones o que has programado tu aleatorizador con cierto sesgo.

Comment: Hola Cristián, no a las adivinanzas, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y aclares que necesitas que haga tu función, (osea que devuelve y que quieres que devuelva) aparte muestras un for, y por otro lado una función, supongo que el for es parte de la función, estoy en lo cierto?, si lo estoy, por favor haz las correcciones necesarias... con respecto al código y sin saber que hace, me llama la atención la ubicación del for y el while, creo que deberían estar al revés, las veces que itera el while, ejecuta **listado_prob.append( juego_cartas( j ))**, que al no cambiar **j** es siempre lo mismo

Comment: Hola. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Probe el orden y estaba bien, sin embargo hice que el contador volviera a cero a la salida del "while" y ahi el "for" me tomaba el resto de los valores. Gracias.

Comment: Dos posibilidades: inicializa el generador sólo una (fuera de la función) o bien inicializalo con un valor distinto cada vez (por ejemplo, dependiendo de "J").